# AWS RDS ORACLE SCHEDULER JOBS RUNNING ONE HOUR EARLIER

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, scheduler, jobs, rds

For some reason from today all my scheduler jobs are running one hour before scheduled:

```
BEGIN 
dbms_scheduler.create_job('"JOB_EXTRACAO_LOOK_11_20"',
job_type=>'PLSQL_BLOCK', job_action=>
'DECLARE
 V_ID_REGIAO VARCHAR2(3) := ''GYN'';
BEGIN
    IF V_ID_REGIAO = 'GYN' THEN
       PRC_RESULTADO_TRADICIONAL (V_ID_REGIAO);
    END IF;
END;'
, number_of_arguments=>0,
start_date=>TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('03-NOV-2019 01.44.54.970684000 PM AMERICA/SAO_PAULO','DD-MON-RRRR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=english'), repeat_interval=> 
'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=13;BYMINUTE=46;BYSECOND=0'
, end_date=>NULL,
job_class=>'"DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS"', enabled=>FALSE, auto_drop=>FALSE,comments=>
'Resultado automatico da extração 11:20 LOOK'
);
dbms_scheduler.set_attribute('"JOB_EXTRACAO_LOOK_11_20"','job_priority',1);
sys.dbms_scheduler.set_attribute('"JOB_EXTRACAO_LOOK_11_20"','NLS_ENV','NLS_LANGUAGE=''AMERICAN'' NLS_TERRITORY=''AMERICA'' NLS_CURRENCY=''$'' NLS_ISO_CURRENCY=''AMERICA'' NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,'' NLS_CALENDAR=''GREGORIAN'' NLS_DATE_FORMAT=''DD-MON-RR'' NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''AMERICAN'' NLS_SORT=''BINARY'' NLS_TIME_FORMAT=''HH.MI.SSXFF AM'' NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT=''DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'' NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT=''HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR'' NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT=''DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR'' NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY=''$'' NLS_COMP=''BINARY'' NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS=''BYTE'' NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP=''FALSE''');
dbms_scheduler.enable('"JOB_EXTRACAO_LOOK_11_20"');
COMMIT; 
END;
```

[Job runs one hour earlier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LBYJ.png)

LOG OF JOB SCHEDULED

```
LOG_ID          116672  
LOG_DATE        03-NOV-19 12.46.02.336034000 PM -03:00  
OWNER           ADMIN   
JOB_NAME        JOB_EXTRACAO_LOOK_11_20     
JOB_SUBNAME     (null)
STATUS          FAILED  
ERRO#           1403    
REQ_START_DATE      03-NOV-19 01.46.00.974251000 PM AMERICA/SAO_PAULO   
ACTUAL_START_DATE   03-NOV-19 01.46.01.107522000 PM AMERICA/SAO_PAULO
```

TIMEZONES CONFIGURANTION

```
TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE = 2019-11-03 12:46:29 -03:00
TIMESTAMP NO TIME ZONE = 2019-11-03 12:46:29 +00:00
AUTO_CONVERTION = 2019-11-03 12:46:29 AMERICA/SAO_PAULO
DBA_SCHEDULER_GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE = DEFAULT_TIMEZONE -3:00
SESSION TIME ZONE =  America/Sao_Paulo
```

Comment: Since today? Are you sure? Could it be since a week ago? Daylight saving time rings a bell to me. Any chance that your database server's time hasn't been adjusted?

Comment: Daylight savings time ended today.

Comment: Apparently, it depends on where we live, @Bob. For us in Europe, it ended previous weekend and no, I still haven't adjusted to it. Waking up too early :(

Comment: Yeah, we're always a little slow here in Amurka. The Ohio state legislature is considering year-long daylight savings time to protect people from the horrors of having to change their clocks, but I suspect they'll run into the same complaints that happened when year-long daylight savings time was tried during the Carter administration, centering around the fact that kids had to walk to school in the dark in the morning. The "easy" fix, which would be to start school an hour later, then runs into further issues with parents needing to go to work, etc. Put another way - time is a problem. :-)

Answer (score 1):

ok the solution is

```
BEGIN
 FOR C1 IN (Select JOB_NAME from user_scheduler_jobs where STATE != 'DISABLED' ORDER BY JOB_NAME) LOOP
     DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( name => C1.JOB_NAME,
                                  attribute => 'START_DATE',
                                  value => SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE '-3:00');
 END LOOP;
END;
```

it will make scheduler ignore the region DST